# Calculate $\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\cos{x} + \sin{x}+1}{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Calculate $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\cos{x} + \sin{x}+1}{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}dx$$

I tried to use substitution $t = \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$ and I got $\int_{\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})}^{1}\frac{2(-t^2+2t+3)}{(-t^2+2t+1)(1+t^2)}dt$, it even seem harder. Anyone can help me solve or give me a hint about thí problem? Thank you

Comment: Hint: try to simplify the fraction in the original integral rather than substituting.

Comment: @ChrisLewis I tried to simplify by $\frac{2\cos{x}+\sin{x}+1}{\sin{x} + \cos{x}} = 1+ \frac{\cos{x}+1}{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}$ then $1 = \sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x}$ but I still cant find how to handle it

Comment: There are a few methods that will work (like @quanto's answer below). An alternative is to write the integrand as $1+\frac{\cos x}{\cos x + \sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x + \sin x}$. Each of these three terms can be integrated in different ways with some trig manipulation.

Comment: Thank you so much @ChrisLewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompose the integrand ad follows

\begin{align}
&\frac{2\cos{x} + \sin{x}+1}{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}\\
=& \ \frac{\frac32(\cos{x} + \sin{x})+\frac12 (\cos{x} - \sin{x}) +1}{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}\\
=&\ \frac32+\frac12 \frac{(\sin{x} +\cos{x})’}{\sin x+\cos x}+ \frac{(\sin{x} -\cos{x})’}{2-(\sin{x}-\cos{x})^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Ohhh, I got it. May I ask you that how do you know that we have to split $2\cos{x}+\sin{x}+1$ into $\frac{3}{2}(\cos{x}+\sin{x}) + \frac{1}{2}(\cos{x}-\sin{x})+1$

Comment: @Jnote The split above allows the subsequent substitutions, i.e. $t= \sin x\pm \cos x$

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Quanto , I have understood your process but I have not understood how you integrated $\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

Comment: @DEBSANKARROY $$(\sin x+\cos x)^2=2-(\sin x-\cos x)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is $\int\frac{2\cos(x)+\sin(x)+1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

Now we can write this integral as

$I=\int\frac{2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx+\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx+\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

$\implies$

$I=\int \frac{[\cos(x)+\sin(x)]+[\cos(x)-\sin(x)]}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx +\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx+\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

$\implies$

$I=\int dx+\int\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{[sin(x)+\cos(x)]+[\sin(x)-\cos(x)]}{[\cos(x)+\sin(x)]}dx+\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

$\implies$

$I=x+\ln|\cos(x)+\sin(x)|+\frac{1}{2}\int dx-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx+\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

$\implies$

$I=x+\ln|\cos(x)+\sin(x)|+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln|\sin(x)+\cos(x)|+\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

Now write $\sin(x)=\frac{2\tan(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1-\tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}$

Therefore,

$\int \frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{1+\tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}{1-\tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2})+2\tan(\frac{x}{2})}dx$

Now substitute $\tan(\frac{x}{2})=u$ and then $\sec^{2}(\frac{x}{2})dx=du$

**Now try to solve. I have given enough hints.**